# Baby Tomato plant - how to care for it

Tags: houseplants, plant-care, tomatoes

I’ve been gifted this gorgeous baby tomato plant and would appreciate advise/tips on how to care for it?

I’ve read online that you should cut leaves off to encourage fruit growth however i’m unsure which leaves to cut?
Also should I water every day?1 [image]

Do I need to re-pot or will it thrive in the pot it came in?

Thanks in advance!!

[image]

Comment: That's clearly not a baby. What is the variety (pruning differs for indeterminate and determinate tomatoes, broadly speaking.) Less broadly speaking, when foliage starts to yellow or brown, cut that foliage off. Brown shriveled leaf on the lower right - get rid of it. With that much fruit in that size pot, it's been getting some serious fertilizer applications wherever it came from, IMHO.

Comment: Why not harvest the ripe fruit before they rot ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are not experienced in growing tomatoes, the best you can do is eating the tomatoes when they are ripe and enjoy the plant as it is.

Care: Watering and as much light as possible, but be careful with direct sunlight, if the plant is not used to such conditions.

If you want more tomatoes then first of all consider that it definitely has not been easy to cultivate this plant. It is not the nature of this genus to form compact and small plants with many berries relative to the amount of leaves.

This is how I **guess** the vendor cultivated your plant:

When the plant was started from seed or as a rooted cutting they continuously removed all branches and all flowers but the two flower branches which are carrying tomatoes today. The plant was allowed to reach a height much taller than today.
When most tomatoes had developed full size, they cut of the top and shortened the leaves. Perhaps they even cut roots off to make it fit to a smaller pot.
This process along with more light and less water initiated ripening of the tomatoes.

To get new tomatoes you will need to let a branch from a leaf corner form a new top. Prefer a branch as low as possible to get flowers closer to the ground.
Then you will have to redo the process allowing more and longer leaves.
If you keep your plant in a small pot, then you should be very accurate with water and fertilizer.

Comment: I don't like this way of gardening, although you can find it in many stores.
The plants look gorgeous but are close to impossible to maintain for a non professional gardener. Usually the first thing I do when I get a new plant is take a look at its rootball. In 99% of all cases the second thing I do is give it a bigger pot to grow in.

Comment: @elPolloLoco Yes, most people do not understand, that such a plant is meant for decoration at a single occasion, and is visually attractive for a few days only.